# Chrome developer tools now showing all the cookies

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome is doing something REALLY weird. It is not showing all the cookies, even though I know for a fact they are there. Let me show you step by step:

### 1. Start with empty cookie set

[image]

### 2. Make login request

This request has the headers to set the cookies for Access Token and Refresh Token

[image]

### 3. Extra request is sent

This request is irrelevant (I think) to the topic, but still, for completion's sake, since it also sets another cookie

[image]

### 4. Check the cookies in the dev tools

The refresh token is not there!

[image]

How is this even possible? I know for a fact that the cookie is there, because when i try to renew my access token, the refresh token is actually sent, so it **must** be there, just not listed.

[image]

Is this just Chrome being wonky??

Comment: While the internal workings of Chrome may be interesting, is this actually causing a problem with any software that you're using or developing?

Comment: It is causing problems with my debugging process

Answer (score 0):

Chrome developer tool has a lot of updates recently. Maybe you can try to try this in Chrome Canary and see if the issue still comes up.